# Rails: Custom text for rails form_for label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, form-for

I want to display a label in `form_for`:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
```

This generates the label "Name", but I want it to be "Your Name". How can I change it?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

The second parameter to `label` helper will allow you to set custom text.

```
<%= f.label :name, 'Your Name' %>
```

Use [Ruby on Rails Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) to look up helper methods.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please let me know how I can look up something like this in the documentation?

Comment: Just go to the above link and type in the method you are looking for in the search box. `label` is listed under `ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder` and `ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper`. `ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder` is the one we are interested in, but there is no description. If you look at the method declaration, you can see that second parameter is `text`. In this example, it's not very straight forward. But that documentation site is _usually_ pretty good.

Answer (score 37):

You can specify custom label text via i18n. In `config/locales/en.yml`, and assuming your user model is named `user`, you can add the following:

```
helpers:
    label:
      user:
        name: Your Name
```

This will allow you to keep using

```
<%= f.label :name %>
```

without having to hardcode `Your Name`.

For more information about i18n, see [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html). Documentation on the `label` refer to [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/label).

Answer (score 1):

#### i18n with rails 5.2.2 this works perfectly.

Translate **labels**, **placeholders**, and **buttons** on *devise* forms or other forms.

```rb
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
   <div class="mt-3">
     <label class="float-left"> <%= f.label t(:email) %> </label>
       <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: t('.emailholder') %>
   </div>
   <div class="mt-3">
     <label class="float-left"> <%= f.label t(:password) %> </label>
       <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control', placeholder: t('.passholder') %>
   </div>

   <div class="button">
     <%= f.button t('.signinbtn'), class: "" %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

locals file:
config/locales/en.yml

```rb
en:
  activerecord:
    ....others

  #Found in Views/devise/seasions/new <form> <*label*>
  email: "Email"
  password: "Password"

  #Views/devise <form> <placeholder & buttom>
  devise: #if your using devise forms
    #seasions/new.html.erb
    new:
      emailholder: "enter email here"
      passholder: "enter password"
      signinbtn: "SignIn"

  ....others
```