# How do I get Rails to use a custom string label for form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, view, label

I have a User model that has a Name attribute, but I plan to use it more as a username.  In the standard for label usage it has :name for the label, so Name shows up when the user sees the form.  How can I force it to use a customer string "Username" label for this attribute in the form so that the :name attribute in the model actually contains the user's username.
Thanks,
Edward

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom text for rails form\_for label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003626/custom-text-for-rails-form-for-label)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add it after the `:name` field like this

```
<%= form.label :name, "Username" %>
```