# How to add symbol (:) in .erb file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I want to add : (symbol) after Username, Email and Password lable tag.
 so form look like this.

**Username : form-field 

Email :   form-field 

password : form-field**

is there  any way to add this symbol?

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-form-label col-sm-1 offset-1 ">
        <%= f.label :Username %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter username", autofocus: true %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-form-label col-sm-1 offset-1">
        <%= f.label :Email  %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.email_field :email,  class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter email" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-form-label col-sm-1 offset-1">
        <%= f.label :password  %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.password_field :email,  class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter password" %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

when  I am adding  : (symbol) after Username,Email,Password it gives SyntaxErrorInTemplate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer should help. 
[Custom text for label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003626/custom-text-for-rails-form-for-label#answer-13003651)

But for your specific issue, you can do:

```
<%= f.label :username, 'Username:' %>
...
<%= f.label :email, 'Email:' %>
```